# Css animated spinner is buggy in IE on Windows 8.1 when used in a React JS component

Tags: windows-8.1, css-transitions, reactjs

I have a spinner that is displayed while making an ajax request. It is in a React JS component. Works fine in most browsers.
However in IE on Windows 8.1, the css spin animation is applied also to the replaced element, i.e. when the spinner div is replaced in the DOM by the content div, the content div is spinning.

Sample code replicating this behaviour:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/build/react.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="js/build/helloworld.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    background-color: LightPink;
}
.box {
    background-color: HotPink;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loader {
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.75s infinite linear;
    animation: spin 0.75s infinite linear;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Js:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function () {
        return {loading:false};
    },
    handleClick:function () {
        this.setState({loading:!this.state.loading});
        console.log(this.state);
    },
    render:function () {

        var content;
        if (this.state.loading) {
            content = <div className="loader"></div>
        } else {
            content = <div className="box"></div>
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</a>
                <div>
                    {content}
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
});
React.render(
    <Component />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The above code is available here:
https://github.com/anulaibar/react-spinner

Running example here:
http://react-spinner.herokuapp.com/

Click once to hide the pink div and show the spinner. Click once more to see the bug where the pink div is spinning.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have IE to test on but try changing this code:

```
    var content;
    if (this.state.loading) {
        content = <div className="loader"></div>
    } else {
        content = <div className="box"></div>
    }
```

To this:

```
    var content;
    if (this.state.loading) {
        content = <div className="loader" key="loader"></div>
    } else {
        content = <div className="box" key="box"></div>
    }
```

The difference is that in the first code React will say "*Oh the className changed, I'll just change `that.className` to `'box'`*".  In the second example it sees the key has changed and recreates the element without even comparing the className.

This is based on my guess that IE isn't removing the animation when the class changes due to a bug, and that removing the element will fix the problem.